# ArrayList Java - Clonar en otra clase

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo 2 clases Peliculas y Main, lo que intento realizar es crear un método en "Peliculas" la cual me permita guardar la lista del ArrayList(lista_peliculas), para luego llamarlo en el case 1. Agradeceré su ayuda.

/**Clase Pelicula**/

```
public class Peliculas {

    private String idpelicula;
    private String nombre;
    private int cantidad_ejemplares;

    public Peliculas() {
        this.idpelicula = "";
        this.nombre = "";
        this.cantidad_ejemplares = 0;
    }

    public Peliculas(String idpelicula, String nombre, int cantidad_ejemplares) {
        this.idpelicula = idpelicula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad_ejemplares = cantidad_ejemplares;
    }
}
```

**Clase principal Main**

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instancias de Peliculas idPelicula, NombrePelicula, cantidad_ejemplares
        ArrayList<Peliculas> lista_peliculas = new ArrayList<Peliculas>();

        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A10", "Elysium", 10));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A20", "Remember the Titans", 2000));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A30", "Coach Carter", 18));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A40", "Snitch", 35));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A50", "Distrito 13", 13));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A60", "The Expendables 3", 23));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Es muy sencillo, no necesitas clonar nada. Primero crea un atributo privado como los que tienes arriba en la clase Peliculas, de tipo ArrayList.

```
private ArryList<Peliculas> lista_peliculas;
```

Después debes crear el método en la clase Película, y en los parámetros tienes que poner que haya que pasarle un ArrayList, algo así:

```
public void nombreDelMetodo(ArrayList<Pelicula> listaPeliculas){

   lista_peliculas = listaPeliculas;
}
```

Después en la clase MAIN, en el lugar desde el que quieres llamar a el método Peliculas, debes instanciar un objeto de la clase Película.

Seria algo asi:

```
Pelicula peli = new Pelicula()
```

Y después para llamar a el método solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente (debes pasarle el ArrayList como parámetro):

```
peli.nombreMétodo(lista_Peliculas);
```

Aún así yo te recomiendo que crees una segunda clase, y que las diferencies, yo a la clase 'Películas' le llamaría Película, y la usaría para instanciar los objetos Película que quieras tal y como haces ya. Y después me crearía una segunda clase llamada AlmacenPeliculas o algo por el estilo, en el cual guardaría el ArrayList con los objetos Película, todo te quedaría mucho más limpio y ordenado.

Answer (score 1):

Crea en tu objeto métodos para guardar y obtener la lista, puedes hacer uso de un `ArrayList` para almacenar la lista de objetos `Peliculas`:

```
public class Peliculas {

    private String idpelicula;
    private String nombre;
    private int cantidad_ejemplares;
    private List<Peliculas> lista_peliculas;

    public Peliculas() {

        this.idpelicula = "";
        this.nombre = "";
        this.cantidad_ejemplares = 0;
    }

    public Peliculas(String idpelicula, String nombre, int cantidad_ejemplares) {

        this.idpelicula = idpelicula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidad_ejemplares = cantidad_ejemplares;

    }

    public void setListaPeliculas(List<Peliculas> lista_peliculas) {
        this.lista_peliculas = lista_peliculas;
    }

    public List<Peliculas> getListaPeliculas() {
        return this.lista_peliculas;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

De esta forma puedes almacenar y obtener la lista de peliculas

```
    //Define variale para almacenar lista de peliculas.
    private static List<Peliculas> listaPeliculas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Peliculas> lista_peliculas = new ArrayList<Peliculas>();

        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A10", "Elysium", 10));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A20", "Remember the Titans", 2000));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A30", "Coach Carter", 18));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A40", "Snitch", 35));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A50", "Distrito 13", 13));
        lista_peliculas.add(new Peliculas("A60", "The Expendables 3", 23));

        //Guarda lista.
        Peliculas peliculas = new Peliculas();
        peliculas.setListaPeliculas(lista_peliculas);

        //Obtiene lista e imprime valores
        listaPeliculas = peliculas.getListaPeliculas();            
        for(Peliculas p : listaPeliculas){
            System.out.println(p.getNombre());
        }


}
```

Como puedes ver, después de almacenar el listado de `peliculas`, puedes obtener la lista en cualquier punto de tu clase `Principal`, mediante.

```
        //Obtiene lista e imprime valores
        listaPeliculas = peliculas.getListaPeliculas();
```

Answer (score 1):

Les dejo el programa en sencillo (Solo para fines educativos.)

```
import java.util.List;

//Object  Pelicula
public class Movie {

    private String idpelicula;
    private String nombre;
    private int cantidadEjemplares;

    public Movie() {
        this.idpelicula = "";
        this.nombre = "";
        this.cantidadEjemplares = 0;
    }

    // Se crea un constructor con parámetros
    public Movie(String idpelicula, String nombre, int cantidadEjemplares) {
        this.idpelicula = idpelicula;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.cantidadEjemplares = cantidadEjemplares;
    }

    // SETTERS AND GETTERS
    public String getIdpelicula() {
        return idpelicula;
    }

    public void setIdpelicula(String idpelicula) {
        this.idpelicula = idpelicula;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getCantidadEjemplares() {
        return cantidadEjemplares;
    }

    public void setCantidadEjemplares(int cantidadEjemplares) {
        this.cantidadEjemplares = cantidadEjemplares;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IDENTIFICADOR: " + idpelicula + ", NOMBRE: " + nombre + ", CANTIDAD: " + cantidadEjemplares;
    }

}





import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Management{

    private static List<Movie> movies= new ArrayList<Movie>();

    public static void addMovie(Movie movie) {  
        movies.add(movie);
    }

    public static void deleteMovie(Movie movie) {   
        movies.remove(movie.getIdpelicula());
    }

    public static Optional<Movie> getMovie(String id) { 
        return movies.stream().filter(mov->mov.getIdpelicula().equalsIgnoreCase(id)).findFirst();       
    }


    public static List<Movie> ListMovies() {    
        return movies;
    }
}





import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        firstStep();
    }

    private static void firstStep() {
        int firstStep = 0;

        while (firstStep == 0 || firstStep>3 ) {
            try {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"BIENVENIDO AL SISTEMA DE PELICULAS.");
                firstStep = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Seleccione que desea hacer. \n" + "1 Consultar por identificador.\n" + "2 Agregar nueva pelicula \n" + "3 Listar peliculas."));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                firstStep = 0;
                System.out.println("Error al escoger elemento. " + e);
            }
        }

        elements(firstStep);
    }

    private static void elements(int firstStep) {

        switch (firstStep) {
        case 1:
            elementDetail();
        case 2:
            AddElement();
        case 3:
            listElements();
        default:
            listElements();
        }
    }

    private static void elementDetail() {
        StringBuilder identifier = new StringBuilder("");

        while (identifier.toString().isEmpty()) {
            identifier.append(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el identificador de la pelicula"));
        }
        Optional<Movie> movie = Management.getMovie(identifier.toString());
        if (movie.isPresent()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado es: \n" + movie.toString());
        } else {
            String n = "";
            while (n.isEmpty() || (!n.toUpperCase().equals("S") && !n.toUpperCase().equals("N"))) {
                n = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("No hay Resultado.\n" + "Si desea salir presione S de lo contrario presione N.");
            }

            if (n.toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                firstStep();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddElement() {
        Movie movie = new Movie();

        while (movie.getIdpelicula().isEmpty()) {
            movie.setIdpelicula(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el Identificador de la pelicula."));
        }

        while (movie.getNombre().isEmpty()) {
            movie.setNombre(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el nombre de la pelicula."));
        }

        while (movie.getCantidadEjemplares()<=0) {
            movie.setCantidadEjemplares(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la existencia.")));
        }

        Management.addMovie(movie);
        String n= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Se ha agregado la pelicula.\n Si desea salir presione S de lo contrario presione N.");
            if (n.toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                firstStep();
            }
        }



    private static void listElements() {
        ArrayList<Movie> movies= (ArrayList<Movie>) Management.ListMovies();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El resultado es: \n" + movies.toString()+"\n");
        String n= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Si desea salir presione S de lo contrario presione N.");
            if (n.toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                firstStep();
            }
        }
}
```

Sugiero lo pruebes con java 1.8 o superior.